# Cannot access a public ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I have been trying to troubleshoot some connection issues, and I'm struggling with a relatively simple setup.

On my (relatively new) AWS account, I create a new Application Load balancer. I configure it in the following way:

- Internet facing
- Use the default VPC that came with the account
- Across all availability zones
- Uses default security group for VPC
- Listens on HTTP:80 and returns a fixed response (status 404)

When I then try and use the new dns name assigned, it just hangs. When using `curl -v` I can see it says:

> Trying :80

`dig` also responds with 3 IPs (I'm assuming for the different zones).

It feels like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm struggling to find it myself.

Can anyone see what I may be missing?

Comment: The default security group does not allow any inbound traffic, only allows outbound IIRC. either way, I would advise against using that group.

Comment: @jordanm, I think that was it. It was my misinterpretation of the default security group. I knew it was something too simple for people to be tripping up on, I couldn't find this problem much on google. If you want to upgrade your comment to an answer, I will mark it correct. If not, I can self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share a print screen of the default security group and LB configuration?
I am almost sure that the default security group has opened ALL inbound traffic but only for itself (security group).

Answer (score 0):

Look 2 things:

1. The security group of ALB should be open to HTTP/HTTPS connections
2. The security group of EC2 for example, should be open to accept ALB group.

I dont know if this is the most safe to manage the security groups, but works.